# Through URL pass parameter to php, but php doesn't get it, Why?

Tags: php, ajax

I create the table and use ajax to pass data.

This is my ajax part, I put the parameter in URL, but php code doesn't read it.

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"system_setting.php?p=add",
        data:"username="+username+"&password="+password+"&nickname="+nickname+"&authority="+authority,
        success:function(data){
            viewData();
        }
    });
```

I use `$page=isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:'';` to judgment parameter, but it doesn't read. Please teach me how should I do, thank you.

Comment: Your'e sending a `POST` request with jquery but you read a `GET` requests data. Use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` in PHP and it should work.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but I didn't work this way. I don't know what my problem.

Comment: While getting request parameters in .php, use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`.

Comment: @ElvisFan I think theres another problem regarding what u put into `data`: you're building up a GET query string, please try using an array (and let jQuery to its thing) and check if post data is served correctly then. See the examples at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for what i mean.

Comment: Sorry, I try more solution, but it still not working. Could you tell me more detail? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Xatenev as you can see i told him about that exact issue youre now pointing at 3 comments later. And why he should use `$_POST`? Well i imply he wants to send a post request by the fact hes using `type:'POST'`.

Comment: @FabianSchöner Your trying to solve a problem that does not exist. What OP has should work, theres some piece missing that causes trouble here, or OP just debuggs `$page` wrong. I don't understand how there can be 4 answers when theres no issue to see in the question, too.

Comment: @ElvisFan Are you sure that you are requesting the correct page/URL? Maybe you want something like `url: BASE_URL + "system_setting.php?p=add"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `POST` instead and add `p=add` in data instead url

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"system_setting.php",
    data:"p=add&username="+username+"&password="+password+"&nickname="+nickname+"&authority="+authority,
    success:function(data){
        viewData();
    }
});
```

And in php

```
$page=isset($_POST['p'])?$_POST['p']:'';
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried your method, but it doesn't work. I saw the data in the net, it say pass the parameter to php, should use $_GET to get parameter. isn't it?

Comment: `$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"system_setting.php",
  data:"p=add&username="+username+"&password="+password+"&nickname="+nickname+"&authority="+authority,
  success:function(data){
   viewData();
  }
 });`

Comment: and php is `$page=isset($_POST['p'])?$_POST['p']:'';`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use only POST or only GET.
Working example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var username="username";
var password="password";
var nickname="nickname";
var authority="authority";


$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"system_setting.php",
        data:"p=add&username="+username+"&password="+password+"&nickname="+nickname+"&authority="+authority,
        success:function(data){
             alert(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

In system_setting.php

```
$page=isset($_POST['p'])?$_POST['p']:'';

echo $page;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
var data = {};
data.username = username;
data.password = password;
data.nickname = nickname;
data.authority = authority; 
data.p = “add”;
$.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"system_setting.php", 
     data: data
 }).done(function(data){
     viewData();
 });
```

Then when you need the data uses `$_POST[]` e.g. `$_POST[‘p’]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,ajax parameter "method" is used for POST and GET.

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "system_setting.php",
        data: { p:"add", username: "unsername", password: "password", nickname:  "nickname", authority:"authority" },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: At initial stage you can write

        $page=isset($_POST['p'])?$_POST['p']:'';
         if($page){
          echo $page;
          exit;
         }

in system_setting.php